# How to implement IDialogService

Tags: wpf, async-await, mvvm-light

I am struggling to implement IDialogService defined in the GalaSoft.MvvmLight assembly. You can get that from the nuget package [MvvmLightLibs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/)

```
public interface IDialogService
{

    Task ShowError(string message, string title, string buttonText, Action afterHideCallback);
    Task ShowError(Exception error, string title, string buttonText, Action afterHideCallback);
    Task ShowMessage(string message, string title);
    Task ShowMessage(string message, string title, string buttonText, Action afterHideCallback);
    Task<bool> ShowMessage(string message, string title, string buttonConfirmText, string buttonCancelText, Action<bool> afterHideCallback);
    Task ShowMessageBox(string message, string title);
}
```

I am trying to implement the first method like so

```
    public Task ShowError(Exception error, string title, string buttonText, Action afterHideCallback)
    {
        //var result = MessageBox.Show("");
        return Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show("whatever"));
        //return Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate () { MessageBox.Show("your stuff"); });
        //var dg = new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show("", ""); });
        //return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(dg);
    }
```

How can i use Messagebox.Show this async method for wpf? Please help.

I am trying to see which works, but so far no luck. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You want to implement ShowError as an async method?

Comment: yes, messagebo in an async method

Answer (score 3):

You say you want your showError to be async, but haven't actually marked the method with the `async` keyword, nor does it await anything:

```
    public async Task ShowError(Exception error, string title, string buttonText, Action afterHideCallback)
    {
        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MessageBox.Show("whatever"));
        Console.WriteLine("awaited Box closed");
    }
```

Example of use:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ShowError(new Exception("Test"), "test", "um", null);
        Console.WriteLine("awaited showError");
    }
```